# Compound Poisson Process, probability generating function

Tags: poisson-distribution, probability-generating-fn

If we have a iid random variables $X_i$ with probability generating function $\xi(t) = E[t^{x_i}]$ and $N$ is Poisson with mean $\lambda$
with Probability generating function :
$$
\begin{aligned}
\phi(t) = \sum_{i \geq 0} { e^{- \lambda} \lambda ^i \over i!} t^i = e^{-\lambda (1-t)}
\end{aligned}
$$

Take $Y = \sum_1^NX_i$ what would the probability generating function be in this case?

$$
\begin{aligned}
E[t^Y] = E[t^{\sum_1^N X_i}] = E[t^{X_1} ... t^{X_N} ] = E[t^{X_1}] ... E[t^{X_N}] = \xi(t)^N
\end{aligned}
$$
But this would be assuming that N is not a random variable. I am confused as to how one would take them both into account?

**EDIT**

So the probability generating function would be:
$$
\begin{aligned}
E[E[t^{\sum_1^N X_i}|X_i]|N] = E[\xi(t)^N | N] = \sum_{i \geq 0} { e^{- \lambda} \lambda ^i \over i!} \xi(t)^i = e^{-\lambda (1- \xi (t))}
\end{aligned}
$$
correct?

Comment: You've gotten part way there; now take the expectation of your last term with respect to the probability distribution of $N$.

Comment: @jbowman is the edit correct?

Comment: Right.  Might want to post your edit as an answer to your question, then accept it - that way everyone knows it was answered and accepted, plus you did figure it out with just one hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on comment:
You've gotten part way there; now take the expectation of your last term with respect to the probability distribution of NN. – jbowman

$$
\begin{aligned}
E[E[t^{\sum_1^N X_i}|X_i]|N] = E[\xi(t)^N | N] = \sum_{i \geq 0} { e^{- \lambda} \lambda ^i \over i!} \xi(t)^i = e^{-\lambda (1- \xi (t))}
\end{aligned}
$$